# Property settings save is not working properly

Tags: c#, properties, settings, save

I have a windows app that takes advantage of the Settings. I have a few user settings that the user can set manually, they are set as User scope. The save method works fine, however if the application is closed and then reopened, the values are set back to the defaults.

here is one example of my code to save:

```
Properties.Settings.Default["LocalDefaultPrinter"] = Default_Printer;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

what could be the problem?

Comment: Is a `*.config` file being generated in the same directory as the assembly?

Comment: And do you have this property scoped as application or user?

Comment: I stated in my original the they are User scope

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was happening?

Comment: Yeah I figured out that is was my fault, there was old code within the code that was overridding the printer selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind everyone. I forgot I had a method in the code that checked if the user set printer was the same as the system set printer and if not then change it to the system printer. Took that method out and all is well.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but I'm used to doing it using the designer generated properties:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.LocalDefaultPrinter = Default_Printer;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

**EDIT:** Well, that's not the problem - I was able to save fine using your approach provided the setting was "User" scoped.  However, if you scope this as 'Application', you won't be able to save the value because that gets stored in your application.config file (application properties don't get saved back to that file on .Save).

Answer (score 2):

When you alter user settings programmatically, you aren't altering the application config file. You are altering a copy of those settings in the user's profile that get merged with the application config at runtime.

Have you checked the user's profile folder for your altered settings? Are they there? If so, your code is functioning properly.

Thanks.
-Jason

Comment: Jason . . . Thank you so much for this tip. It has solved the riddle that I have been searching for now for days. I'd +20 it if I could.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to these possibilities, understand that user settings are scoped to the version number of the executable.  So, if you automatically increment your build or change your build number during debugging, you will lose any settings already updated by a prior version of the application.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone having problems in WPF.

Call the `Settings.Default.Upgrade()` to retrieve the non-default values when you want to use the settings you saved.

Answer (score 0):

Application scoped settings are read only whereas user scoped settings are read/write. Calling `Save()` will persist the user scoped settings between application sessions. If `LocalDefaultPrinter` is application scoped this will not persist between sessions.

[This post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28VS.80%29.aspx) provides information on how to make use of the settings in its entirety.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced a similar problem with one specific key in user settings.
To solve it, I tried deleting the key and adding it back.  Final solution, I added a new key with a new name it worked.  Dumb solution but it worked.